# General way to provide the event argument in a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, arguments

I am declaring the event argument for years and years on roughly the same manner:

```
 element.onclick = function(e){};
 element.onclick = function(event){};

 element.addEventListener("click", function(e){}, false);
 element.addEventListener("click", eventHandler, false); //preferred version

 function eventHandler(e){} 

 etc.
```

- Does it have to be `e` or `event`.
- Is it appended as the last argument or can it also be the first?

Can you do this:

```
 function eventHandler(e, a, b, c, d){}
```

Is `e` still referring to the event or is it `d`?

Or to make the above work you need to explicitly use the keyword `event`?

So the general question is: *What are the rules of thumb when it comes to declaring the event argument within a function in JavaScript?*

Comment: can name arguments what you want, it's order that matters ... and using same name within the function

Comment: chrome names it event if left out, so i guess event is more standard, but i like e. it's only the first argument/parameter that matters for most (all?) dom events.

Comment: @dandavis: DOM event handlers only receive a single argument: http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#eventtarget

Comment: Are you talking about DOM event handlers, or event handlers in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I assume you are referring to about DOM events handlers.

> Does it have to be `e` or `event`.

It doesn't matter. It could be `ajdlahksjd` for all we care.

> Is it appended as the last argument or can it also be the first?

The event object will always be passed as first argument to the handler.

> Can you do this:
>
> ```
>  function eventHandler(e, a, b, c, d){}
> ```
>
> Is `e` still referring to the event or is it `d`?

It depends on how you bind the event handler. If you just assign it it will be `e`. If you already bind other values to the parameters, e.g. via `.bind`, it will be the first un-bound parameter. However, that doesn't really have anything to do with event handlers. The event handler itself will also get the event object as first argument.

> Or to make the above work you need to explicitly use the keyword `event`?

`event` is not a keyword. You can name the parameter however you want to.

> What are the rules of thumb when it comes to declaring the event argument within a function in JavaScript?

There is none. There is no magic statically inspection of your event handler. It's simply a function that accepts an argument, that's it.

However, there is certainly a *convention* to name the parameter `e` or `event`, simply because it's reasonable name for a variable that represents an event object.

Comment: event is not an official keyword, but it is present. <html><b onclick=alert(event.type)>test</b></html> for example...

Comment: True. Because the browser converts that to `function(event) { alert(event.type); }`.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in HTML 4, but HTML5 defines this behavior: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes

Comment: @FelixKling; I totally understand your answer. Thanks, but can you explain this: `element.onkeydown = test.bind(this, 1, 2, 3, 4); function test(a, b, c, d, e)`. `e` is the event handler.

Comment: @Mouser: That's exactly the case I thought about writing, but didn't (now I did). Of course if you already `.bind` arguments to the function, the event object with the first non-bound argument. However, that has nothing to do with event handlers, that's how `.bind` and partial application works. Example: `function foo(a, b) { }; var bound = foo.bind(null, 1); bound(2);`. Here, `a=1` and `b=2`. Expanded my answer a little.

Comment: @FelixKling isn't `1` in `foo.bind(1);` referred by the keyword `this` instead of `a`?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think there's no rule about this, but the great Nicholas Zakas, in his book **[Maintainable JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449327680)**, tells that if you want to have a function easy to test and maintain, you never have to declare the event as follows:

```
function myFunction(event) {}
```

Instead, you'd have to declare the arguments that the function needs:

```
function myFunction(clientX, clientY) {}
```

And when you call the function, you must pass the arguments from the object event:

```
// This won't work on IE8 and older versions.
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    myFunction(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}, false);
```

When you or another guy from your team have to test this function, s/he doesn't need to emulate any event.

Comment: And where is `event` coming from? Now you need another event handler whom the event object is passed as the first argument which can then be used to fill the parameters of `myFunction` O.o

Comment: Yes, but you can use an `anonymous function`. Using this approach, you are uncoupling the function -with the logic- from the event and you are safe to test it.

Comment: @LeonardoManrique: but doesn't that imply one more place to edit when making changes? it feels a bit repetitive too. i can see the desire, and angular makes good use of such convention, but i'm not sold on having two functions for every little action. is it worth it?